# How to update icon dynamically in contacts for my android app?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, icons

I am working on a app which add its icon in android default contacts app just like whatsApp icon appears in contact info. I want to update my apps icon dynamically on receiving some events, say a user comes online, then icon in contact list should be different then the icon shown when user is offline.

Can anyone suggest any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume your contact list is a ListView, and that you have an adapter that inflates each cells layout (that is, displays the icon and name of the contact).

Whenever you detect a change has occurred (an event was received) (maybe consider using a Loader if you aren't already), you should be able to call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to update the cells.

Comment: Sorry I have not clearly mentioned in question this before that I want to update this in android's default contacts app. In contacts app we can see whatsApp, skype icons in each contact info. SimiIarly have added my apps icon. Now I want to update that icon dynamically in contacts app based on events.